# How do I use JavaScript regexes to return objects with in a array?

Tags: json, loops, google-apps-script, nested-object

I am trying to use regexes to convert my JSON file that is returned into separate objects using `[]` not `()` so I can then push an id out of each of these objects. I am able to get the intial JSON object to return I need to turn those objects into arrays.

reference: [Google APp script Get Properties](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/properties#getKeys())

## JS

```html
   var GetShapeProps = [{
({
  id: "6:3",
  absoluteBoundingBox: [{
    x: -406,
    y: -274,
    width: 437,
    height: 56
  })
}),
({
  id: "10:3",
  absoluteBoundingBox: [{
    x: -406,
    y: -201,
    width: 437,
    height: 56
  })
}),
({
  id: "10:4",
  absoluteBoundingBox: [{
    x: -406,
    y: -122,
    width: 437,
    height: 56
  })
}),
({
  id: "10:5",
  absoluteBoundingBox: [{
    x: -406,
    y: -28,
    width: 437,
    height: 56
  })
}]


function prop1(obj1, getFrameProps, b, args){
  function prop2(obj1, getFrameProps, keys, b, kind) {
    var GetShapesProps = GetFrammeProps;
    obj1 = PropertiesService.GetShapesProps();

    // Sets several script properties, then retrieves them and logs them.
    GetShapesProaps = GetShapesProaps.getProperties();
    for (var id in GetShapesProaps) {
      if (id > GetShapesProaps) {
        var newObject = (kind, GetShapesProaps[id]);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

## output Srings:

```
[id: "6:3"]

[{ x: -406,
y: -274,
 width: 437,
 height: 56}]
```

## Error Returned

```
TypeError: Cannot find function replace in object 
[object Object],[object Object],
[object Object],[object Object],
[object Object],[object Object].
```

[image]

Comment: Can you provide the script for replicating the issue? And also, can you provide the sample input values and the output values you expect?

Comment: @Tanaike https://script.google.com/d/1hYBSIW-bl10rkM7F8Ls8V69aLkcNQBmf0sccKphZ71HZ07DCUtPx7-XW/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Thank you for replying. I saw the link and your script. But I cannot find the script in your question from your shared script. And also I cannot find the sample input values and the output values you expect. Can you explain about them?

Comment: @Tanaike it would be the one that says edit me

Comment: Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, I couldn't understand about your goal from your replying. This is due to my poor English skill. I apologize for this.